# How to predict a True/False event

Tags: algorithm, statistics, prediction

I have some measurements on a system (x, y, z, ..) over many trials. The system produces a true or false output. I would like to take my data and produce a predictor function of x,y, z,  that would best predict the system outcome.

I am used to methods for approximating smooth outcomes like approximating a graph, but don't know the terms to search for when the outcome is true/false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for `multivariate classification`.

In your case you just have two classes (true and false).

The [Wikipedia article on statistical classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification#Algorithms) has a list of commonly used algorithms.

You can also search for `multivariate regression` which attempts to model a real value as function of several values where in your case the possible values are a discrete set (0,1).
One would have to take a decision on whether the predicted outcome is True or False based on the regression function's output (e.g. assume True if the output is > 0.5 and False if it's <= 0.5).

Note that there is also https://stats.stackexchange.com/ where you could get more detailed answers related to the analysis of data.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically wanting the probability of TRUE or FALSE. A standard technique is [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). Logistic regression is a useful way of describing the relationship between a binary response variable and some independent variables. Since the output is a probability, it is easily interpretable.

There are standard libraries in most languages to implement logistic regression.

Answer (score 1):

A neural network seems like a perfect fit for your problem.

Comment: -1: "A Turing machine can solve that problem" isn't an answer, and neither is yours.

Comment: @bdares: IMO, the level of detail of my response is in accordance with the level of detail of the question.

Comment: Still, while you can use NNs, you could also use binary decision diagrams, clustering, SVMs... Saying NNs are a "perfect fit" is probably an overstatement.

Comment: @missingno, saying that something is "a perfect fit" does not imply that other ways are not.